# How to get text in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-re

I'm trying to get the string  "Carlos Pellegrini 551, C1009ABK Buenos Aires, Argentina" using BS but I'm having problems. (It's just before the  at the end)

```
<span class="
hp_address_subtitle
js-hp_address_subtitle
jq_tooltip
" rel="14" data-source="top_link" data-coords="," data-component="tooltip" data-tooltip-text="
<p>Ubicación <strong>excelente</strong>, ¡puntuada con 9,3/10! <small>(puntaje basado en <strong>Más recomendado</strong> comentarios)</small></p>
<p>Valorado por las personas <strong>después de hospedarse en</strong> el Hotel Panamericano Buenos Aires.</p>
" data-tooltip-animation="false" tabindex="0" data-bbox="-58.4028009366937,-34.6199039159457,-58.3590682554297,-34.5839730827995" data-node_tt_id="location_score_tooltip" data-width="350" title="" aria-describedby="tooltip-1">
Carlos Pellegrini 551, C1009ABK Buenos Aires, Argentina
</span>
```

I tried the following:

```
soup.find(attrs={'class':"hotel_address_subtitle"}).get_text()
```

But I get None ad a result.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to only find text on the website:

```
soup.find_all(text=True)
```

instead of:

`soup.find(attrs={'class':"hotel_address_subtitle"}).get_text()`

try:

```
for element in soup.find_all(text=True):
    print(element)
```

**edit** after I saw your comment, try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.booking.com/hotel/ar/panamericano-buenos-aires.es-ar.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
output = soup.find("span", {"class": "hp_address_subtitle"})
print(output.text)
```

outputs

```
Carlos Pellegrini 551, C1009ABK Buenos Aires, Argentina
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. 
The full soup has much more text than that, and I need to pinpoint the exact location of this text and I don't know exactly how.
[link](https://www.booking.com/hotel/ar/panamericano-buenos-aires.es-ar.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked like a charm and will help me in further scraping.
I accepted your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"select_one"`. you can try it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc='''<span class="
hp_address_subtitle
js-hp_address_subtitle
jq_tooltip
" rel="14" data-source="top_link" data-coords="," data-component="tooltip" data-tooltip-text="
<p>Ubicación <strong>excelente</strong>, ¡puntuada con 9,3/10! <small>(puntaje basado en <strong>Más recomendado</strong> comentarios)</small></p>
<p>Valorado por las personas <strong>después de hospedarse en</strong> el Hotel Panamericano Buenos Aires.</p>
" data-tooltip-animation="false" tabindex="0" data-bbox="-58.4028009366937,-34.6199039159457,-58.3590682554297,-34.5839730827995" data-node_tt_id="location_score_tooltip" data-width="350" title="" aria-describedby="tooltip-1">
Carlos Pellegrini 551, C1009ABK Buenos Aires, Argentina
</span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
result = soup.select_one("span").text

print(result)
```

Output will be:

```
Carlos Pellegrini 551, C1009ABK Buenos Aires, Argentina
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the thing is that this text in not the first text in the whole soup neither is the first span.